# I have tried using a public void function from a different script and error message CS1061 pops up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in Unity with dialogue boxes and have one script made for putting the dialogue box on the screen and another to have the actual text put on the dialogue box.There is one function in the first script I have to use in the second to make it work. The problem however is that when I try to reference the first script it always occur an error.

The error message is:
Assets\scripts\dialogueHolder.cs(29,18): error CS1061: 'dialogueManager' does not contain a definition for 'ShowBox' and no accessible extension method 'ShowBox' accepting a first argument of type 'dialogueManager' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

First code

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class dialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject dialogueBox;
    public Text dialogueText;

    public bool activeDialogue;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (activeDialogue == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            dialogueBox.SetActive(false);
            activeDialogue = false;
        }
    }

    public void ShowBox(string lines)
    {
        activeDialogue = true
        dialogueBox.SetActive(true);
        dialogueText.text = lines;
    }
}
```

Second code

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class dialogueHolder : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public string dialogue;
    private dialogueManager dMan;
    public GameObject Manager;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        dMan = Manager.GetComponent<dialogueManager>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
      if(other.gameObject.name=="Shadow")
      {
          if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
            dMan.ShowBox(dialogue);
      }
    }
}
```

I can clearly see that the function ShowBox I am trying to access from the first script is the problem. But I can't figure out what to do with the code to make it work. I have tried different methods to try and reference the Class dialogueManager. For an example I have tried refrencing the actual gameobject in the game or the script alone but I can't seem to get it to work. If I remove the function ShowBox the code will run but I need the ShowBox function to actually make the dialogue boxes in my game to work so that is not a solution.

Comment: Is there any other errors in the console window? Have you tried to restart Unity?

Comment: I have tried restarting Unity and there is a different error message now, Assets\scripts\dialogueHolder.cs(29,18): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'lines' of 'dialogueManager.ShowBox(string)'

Comment: Hold on, I fixedthat error and now It might work

Answer (score 0):

"activeDialogue = true" maybe you should put a ";" after this

Comment: That was unfortunately not the problem. It was most likely a typo made when I was trying to copy the script unto the post...